# API expects queries to look like `foo?bar[baz]` instead of `foo?bar=baz`. Is this possible with @QueryParam?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, resty-gwt

Our team needs to consume a rest-ish API that expects path parameters in the form of

```
api/v1/foo?bar[baz]
```

instead of `api/v1/foo?bar=baz` or `bar=[baz]`

and

```
api/v1/foo?filter[baz][baz.id][id]=123
```

instead of .. I don't even know. They somehow map this to php arrays and the second example should return every Foo that has baz.id=123.

Now, if I use `@QueryParam("bar") String bar`, the result is `foo?bar=[baz]` (if `bar.equals("[baz]")` of course).

Is there any way I can influence how resty generates the query string? So far the only way to achieve this seems to be writing my own `RestServiceClassCreator` and replace the default one via deferred binding. Though even then I'm not sure if stuff like the second examples could be covered by this.

Comment: Do you mean to reference `@PathParam` there or `@QueryParam()`?

Comment: `@QueryParam` of course. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Already the second case shows that one would be trying to squeeze the square thingy in the round hole. So try a custom solution.